# AJAX Post not capturing response after subsequent loading of another dynamic page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The following code is used to allow users to send enquiries. The contact form is loaded on initial loading of website and if the user then immediately accesses the contact form and processes an enquiry the code works as intended. The problem occurs if the user first clicks on another tab which uses AJAX to dynamically load the content and subsequently accesses the contact page and sends an enquiry.

Although the message is sent, the returned success message from the server is just being echoed on the screen and all content has been lost. Does anybody know what the cause is?

**Jquery and AJAX code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var request;
$("#EnquiryForm").submit(function(event){
if (request) {
request.abort();
}
event.preventDefault();
var $form = $(this);
var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
var serializedData = $form.serialize();
$inputs.prop("disabled", true);
request = $.ajax({

url: "index.php",
type: "POST",
data: serializedData
});
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    alert(response);                
});
request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.error("The following error occurred: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
});
request.always(function () {
$("#EnquiryForm")[0].reset();
     $('#seniorEnquiries').prop('checked', true);
    $('input').iCheck({
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-red',
    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
  });   

$inputs.prop("disabled", false);});
$('input').iCheck('enable');
})
})
```

**PHP**

```
$message = sendEnquiry();
echo $message;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs on `document ready` and sets up the event hook `submit`, since the tab HTML is loading via Ajax it has no event hooks attached to it and the `document ready` is not triggered again, the form is submitted as a normal post/get rather than via Ajax.

Fix it by setting up the `submit` hook every time the form html is loaded in the tab.

Comment: I fixed the problem by placing the code in the contact form whereas before it was in a separate javascript file which was loaded during the load of the home page. Thanks for your answer.